# Perl 5.26 on RHEL 7 error - cgi-error - libperl.so.rh-perl526-5.26: cannot open shared object file

Tags: perl, cgi, rhel7

I am attempting to run perl CGI script on RHEL 7, i've used yum installer and it's successfully installed 5.26, i can run perl programs from terminal without problem, but when i run a simple CGI script it writes error to httpd/error.log. I've posted the exact error below.

**enabled software collection**

`$scl enable rh-perl526 bash`

`perl -v`

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 27 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

`$which perl`

/opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/bin/perl

`$perl -e 'print "Hello Perl\n"'`

Hello Perl

## When i run a simple CGI script from browser or curl -XGET, i got 500 internal server for

**http://serverip/cgi-bin/test-cgi.pl**

> apache error

```
[Wed Mar 24 21:24:38.308033 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 9437] [client x.x.x.x:35220] AH01215: /opt/rh/rh-perl526/root/usr/bin/perl: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.rh-perl526-5.26: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Wed Mar 24 21:24:38.308245 2021] [cgi:error] [pid 9437] [client x.x.x.x:35220] End of script output before headers: test.cgi.pl
```

I've added libperl.so path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in .bashrc and i've rh-perl526-perl-libs.x86_64 package installed.

While installing rh-perl526, i noticed it also installed default perl on system as well due to YUM dependency

any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Which user is the web server running under? Which version of Perl does that user use?

Comment: when the script is run by the web server, it's unlikely to be sourcing .bashrc, so LD_LIBRARY_PATH won't be set

Comment: it’s my id and runs 5.26

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in .bashrc not passed to apache i think.

Comment: Thanks @Dave Mitchell for hints, i have added below line in http.conf and it worked

SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/libperl

Answer (score 0):

LD_LIBRARY_PATH needs to set in apache http.conf file

i have added below line in httpd.conf and it worked

SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/libperl

I also removed perl 5.16 from system using yum.